# how to download page source when some operation on page is needed

Tags: html, asp.net, web

I am using below code to download my target web site source and extract my required information .

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
        Client.DownloadFile("target page url", " D:/myTextFile.txt");
    }
```

But in some cases in my target web site i need to press a key to load my required information. 
For example in [this page](http://new.tse.ir/en/ask-bid.html?cat=cash&section=bid) I should press "More" Button to see full data.
How can i reach this object?

Comment: You have to adapt the site then, and then pass a querystring parameter like `yourTaretUrl?more=true` to initially load all the details...if the parameter is not supplied ..load the page as usual

Comment: In my example there is not any query string parameter when i click "more" button.

Comment: then adapt it to handle a "more" parameter... then u can use it from your WebClient...

Comment: if the site is using ajax you have to make additional requests. use fiddler to find out what to send.